# Opposite of a deposit refund

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I'm developing a database and coming up with the statuses for a given account with regard to their Glassware Deposit. ($$ paid upfront, but refundable at the end)

I have

- Never Paid
- Paid
- Refunded
- **Kept**

Is there a better way than **Kept** to describe the opposite of a deposit refund? (i.e. They broke their glassware and don't get a refund)

Comment: I think I missed something. Better way than what?

Comment: @Kit: Better way than "kept".

Comment: Is it possible that only part of it is kept?

Comment: If it wasn't _refunded_, I suppose it was _funded_ :)

Comment: @Callithumpian That implies `re` is a negative prefix~ which doesn't seem accurate ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did put this in as a comment, but the more I think about it the more it seems to me it's the best option, so here it is as an answer that can be voted on.

I think **forfeit** is commonly used in respect of security deposits which are not refunded. To my ear this can function as a past participle/adjective even without the **-ed** suffix, but I suspect many might prefer the more "grammatical" form.

---

EDIT: As suggested above, ***will be forfeit*** has been gaining traction against the "regular" past participle / adjectival form ***will be forfeited***. As [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20be%20forfeited%2Cwill%20be%20forfeit&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20forfeited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20forfeit%3B%2Cc0) shows, the noninflected form now accounts for 2 out of 5 BrE usages. The shift is [less marked in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20be%20forfeited%2Cwill%20be%20forfeit&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20forfeited%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20forfeit%3B%2Cc0), but it's happening there too.

Comment: +1.  I've seen this usage too and it nicely conveys "hey, the guy who didn't get his money did something to cause that" (vs. "we didn't get around to paying him").

Comment: @Shad: [This](http://www.encyclo.co.uk/webster/F/62) link seems to agree *forfeit* is okay as a past participle and an adjective.

Answer (score 4):

Is this like a security deposit (when renting property)?  Since a security deposit isn't usually binary—you can have part of it returned and part not to pay for damages—would you be better off thinking of this as "amount returned" (and zero means you kept it all)?

If it really is binary in your case and you don't like *kept*, consider *retained* or *not returned*.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a superior replacement for "Refunded" in the schema outlined, I think.  But the OP is asking for a replacement for "Kept" in the case where the deposit isn't refunded.

Comment: +1 for *retained*, which seems totally natural to me in this context. One other possibility that occurs to me is *forfeit*, which to my ear at least can function as a past participle/adjective even without the **-ed** suffix.

Comment: +1 In this case it is binary (no partial refunds). I like _retained_, it just doesn't hit the note of finality I was looking for. Thanks for the thoughtful response.

Answer (score 1):

I would say **Used** rather than **Kept**.  This aligns with the basic idea that the only reason not to return deposit monies is because they needed to be used for whatever purpose the deposit had, and makes it sound a bit less like "oh, hey, we just decided to keep this money".  If you wanted to go slightly fancier, you could say **Expensed**, as in "used to cover an expense".

Comment: +1 I like how naturally it would fit into the schema, Deposit Paid, Deposit Refunded, Deposit Used; and the finality is nice too. In this case though, I think it has too much meaning for my purpose. The person I am developing for may not actually _use_ the deposit instantly upon updating the DB, but the deposit _is_ forfeit instantly upon updating the DB. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the order is completed, so there is no longer an opportunity to return the item for a refund even if it gets broken, I'd suggest **completed** or **fulfilled** to describe the order status.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case it is the status of the deposit, not the order.

Answer (score 0):

> **Hold**
> [hohld]
> /verb (used with object)
>
> 2. to set aside; reserve or retain.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hold)

I would say, "***held***".

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest "cashed" as having very little chance of derogatory impact. When a user breaks glass he has, in effect, cashed his deposit in exchange for the glass; or he could effectively purchase the wares by not returning them: the same is if he had paid cash in anticipation, before or after the fact, of forfeiting the deposit. For you and your rent (to own?) enterprise, cashed covers all variations pertaining to how the deposit might be booked as un-returnable or un-returned; that is, mutually converted from inventory to sales proceeds.